# Remove Scrollbars from Parent Window when Fancybox Loads

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox-2

I've searched for this topic, I am sure there is a solution out there but I'm not looking for the right thing...

I am using a customized version of Twitter Bootstrap 2.x (Fluid Responsive) with top and bottom full-width fixed navigation bars and Fancybox 2.1.4

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

bootstrap.min.css

bootstrap-responsive.min.css

modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js

jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5

jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4

jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4

Anyways, my problem is occurring while using fancybox. All of my fancybox content is using iframes (even the content without iframes appears to do the same thing but i figured i would include that).

**When you click on a link the fancbox box appears on the screen and then the parent window produces a scrollbar (behind the fancybox). It isn't hurting anything but it just looks tacky. I am producing HTML5 content to go in a kiosk so I do not want scrollbars to appear.**

Comment: with all this pieces of code, you're almost half way to a complete jsfiddle which would allow us to help you ;)

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/6XmER/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the overflow:hidden on the div with the scrollbar when you click on the link. Never really used jfiddle, but according to that just over riding the class in the fancybox css will do the trick.

Throw this in one of your custom css files:

```
 .fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay { overflow:hidden; }
```

make sure to load your custom css **after** you load the fancybox css so yours takes precedence.

Be careful with this, because if one of the pictures you are overlaying is extermely tall (taller than your current window view) then you won't be able to see the whole image.

You can use some javascript to resize the image according to the height of the window if this is a pressing issue.